# Can variable be a type guard

Tags: typescript

Is it possible, that a variable can act as a type guard?

```
type Union = string | {prop: string};

function test(u: Union) {
  if (typeof u === "string") {
    u;
    //  ^? (parameter) u: string
  }

  if (typeof u === "object") {
    u;
    //  ^?(parameter) u: { prop: string }
  }

  let check = typeof u === "object";
  //  ^?let check: boolean

  if (check) {
    u.prop;
    //  ^?(parameter) u: Union
  }
}
```

[TS Play Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigZ2AJwXAcygB8oBvMHJMALi13wIF8BuAKDYDMBXOAY2DJUwCNgAU3OvCEBKMhyiKoCTmNCQknKN3RoMAImx5C+uWyUXt5pQHobigHoB+a4qYKlKteAibtugyQAIwArCAFTeUslblcoO0cXC3c4gBsIYCg+AAtwgGt0KHVfLR09QNDw4H12CwSoZw9FLxz8s2jFbgA6Smo4+sbktiYgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables don't have narrowing abilities but constants have !

```
const check = typeof u === "object";

if(check){
    u.prop // { prop: string }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigZ2AJwXAcygB8oBvMHJMALi13wIF8BuAKDYDMBXOAY2DJUwCNgAU3OvCEBKMhyiKoCTmNCQknKN3RoMAImx5C%20uWyUXt5pQHobigHoB%20a4qYKlKteAibtugyQAIwArCAFTeUslblcoO0cXC3c4vhRsKD4AC3CAa3QodV8tHT1A0PDgfXYLBKhnD0UvbLyzaMVuADpKaji6huS2JiA)

Comment: The if-block should convert ```u```to string by ```if(check){u = u.prop}```. But then ```u``` becomes Union again. My goal was to convert ```u``` to string? Do you know how to do that, without an extra type guard function around the if?

Comment: Note: [Introduced in TS4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#cfa-aliased-conditions)